# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ubuntu/PyCode/busData/_14data.gz' using Python Flask WGSI on AWS EC2 (ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, wsgi, permission-denied, flask-restful

I have used Python and Flask to construct an API to display the realtime bus information in the city several.

It worked well on Microsoft Azure and Heroku platform. However, when I deployed the same code on Amazon AWS EC2 (ubuntu 16.04) using WGSI, some "Permission Denied" occured.

The error is from the several "url retrieve and save file" actions in my code like

`urllib.urlretrieve(_14url, "./_14data.gz")`

I think it is because I don't have the privilege to access the dir (`"/var/www/html/flaskapp"`) where the code run "virtually"(it just use a link to the dir when my code exists actually ==> `"/home/ubuntu/PyCode/flaskapp"`).

So I change the code to absolute path

`urllib.urlretrieve(_14url, "/home/ubuntu/PyCode/busData/_14data.gz")`

and add this line to the begining of the code

`os.chdir("/home/ubuntu/PyCode/busData/")`

to insure it will not to access the trouble dir (`"/var/www/html/flaskapp"`)

I think it will be OK.
But.... Things happens as usual as the same error message below:

```
[Sun Oct 22 15:13:24.634958 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 22877:tid 140690232469248] ----------http://ec2-34-215-96-32.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/mapnet/----------
[Sun Oct 22 15:13:25.753003 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 22877:tid 140690232469248] [client 140.112.250.168:2736] [2017-10-22 15:13:25,751] ERROR in app: Exception on /mapnet/ [GET]
[Sun Oct 22 15:13:25.753027 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 22877:tid 140690232469248] [client 140.112.250.168:2736] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Oct 22 15:13:25.753030 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 22877:tid 140690232469248] [client 140.112.250.168:2736]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
[Sun Oct 22 15:13:25.753032 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 22877:tid 140690232469248] [client 140.112.250.168:2736]     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
[Sun Oct 22 15:13:25.753034 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 22877:tid 140690232469248] [client 140.112.250.168:2736]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
[Sun Oct 22 15:13:25.753036 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 22877:tid 140690232469248] [client 140.112.250.168:2736]     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
[Sun Oct 22 15:13:25.753037 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 22877:tid 140690232469248] [client 140.112.250.168:2736]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
[Sun Oct 22 15:13:25.753039 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 22877:tid 140690232469248] [client 140.112.250.168:2736]     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
[Sun Oct 22 15:13:25.753041 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 22877:tid 140690232469248] [client 140.112.250.168:2736]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
[Sun Oct 22 15:13:25.753043 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 22877:tid 140690232469248] [client 140.112.250.168:2736]     rv = self.dispatch_request()
[Sun Oct 22 15:13:25.753045 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 22877:tid 140690232469248] [client 140.112.250.168:2736]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
[Sun Oct 22 15:13:25.753046 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 22877:tid 140690232469248] [client 140.112.250.168:2736]     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
[Sun Oct 22 15:13:25.753048 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 22877:tid 140690232469248] [client 140.112.250.168:2736]   File "/var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.py", line 447, in mapnet
[Sun Oct 22 15:13:25.753050 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 22877:tid 140690232469248] [client 140.112.250.168:2736]     urllib.urlretrieve(_14url, "./_14data.gz")
[Sun Oct 22 15:13:25.753052 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 22877:tid 140690232469248] [client 140.112.250.168:2736]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 98, in urlretrieve
[Sun Oct 22 15:13:25.753053 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 22877:tid 140690232469248] [client 140.112.250.168:2736]     return opener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
[Sun Oct 22 15:13:25.753055 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 22877:tid 140690232469248] [client 140.112.250.168:2736]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 249, in retrieve
[Sun Oct 22 15:13:25.753057 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 22877:tid 140690232469248] [client 140.112.250.168:2736]     tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
[Sun Oct 22 15:13:25.753059 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 22877:tid 140690232469248] [client 140.112.250.168:2736] IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ubuntu/PyCode/busData/_14data.gz'
```

I have try some `chmod` or `chown` to treat the trouble dir, but it seems that it didn't work.
How can I fix this problem QAQ...

Comment: Can you share the output of `ls -ld /home/ubuntu/PyCode` and `ls -ld /home/ubuntu/PyCode/busData`.

Comment: @Madhukar Mohanraju <ls -ld /home/ubuntu/PyCode> ==> drwxrwxr-x 5 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct 21 09:17 /home/ubuntu/PyCode     <ls -ld /home/ubuntu/PyCode/busData> ==> drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct 21 09:17 /home/ubuntu/PyCode/busData
   ,Thanks~~

Comment: as which user does the python code gets invoked? and who is the owner of the code `flaskapp.py`?

Comment: @Madhukar Mohanraju it is the same user named "ubuntu" (default user name in aws EC2)

Comment: @Madhukar Mohanraju Oh! I know what you mean! They are different users!!!! And I use <sudo chmod -R a+w /var/www> & <sudo chmod -R a+w ~/PyCode/busData>. The error is gone!!!

Comment: Nice !!! I was about to ask you to give `write` permission, once you confirmed they were different users.